# Create array in convenience init

Tags: arrays, swift, initializer

I was learning S.O.L.I.D right now from the book iOS programming Big Nerd Ranch. I want to make a an array from convenience init but I have a problem, I want to display the text and image like the exact order of an array but I don't know how. here I show you my code

This is my item class

```
class Item: NSObject {
var imageName: String
var label: String

init(imageName: String, label: String) {
    self.imageName = imageName
    self.label = label

    super.init()
}

convenience init(list: Bool = false) {
    if list {
        let imageList = ["milada-vigerova", "david-rodrigo", "quran"]
        let labelList = ["Fiqih", "Hadist", "Tafsir"]

        let sortImageName = imageList[imageList.count - 1]
        let sortLabel = labelList[labelList.count - 1]

        self.init(imageName: sortImageName, label: sortLabel)
    } else {
        self.init(imageName: "", label: "")
    }
  }
}
```

this my ItemStore class that create an array from Item class

```
class ItemStore {
var allItems = [Item]()

@discardableResult func createItem() -> Item {
    let newItem = Item(list: true)
    allItems.append(newItem)

    return newItem
}

// I make this for in loop to make the table view numberOfSection will return 3 of an allItems
init() {
    for _ in 0..<3 {
        createItem()
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good Lord, this is pretty *nerdy* and cumbersome code.

First of all a struct is sufficient, you get the initializer for free

```
struct Item {
    let imageName: String
    let label: String
}
```

In `ItemStore` create the array instantly

```
class ItemStore {
    var allItems = [Item]()

    func createArray() {
        allItems = [Item(name: "Fiqih", image: "milada-vigerova"),
                    Item(name: "Hadist", image: "david-rodrigo"),
                    Item(name: "Tafsir", image: "quran")]
    }
}
```

In the table view return `allItems.count` in `numberOfRows` (not `numbersOfSection`)

Comment: haha my nerdy just because I follow that book, I see so as long as the S.O.L.I.D principles being applied code like above does not matter right.